# Using Util:RegistrySearch to search 64-bit registry in WiX setup project

Tags: wix

Consider the following code:

```
<Wix xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
<Product>
  <Property Id="MyProperty">
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="MyRegistrySearch" Root="HKLM"
      Key="SOFTWARE\MyCompany\MyApp" Win64="yes"
      Value="MyRegistryValue" Variable="MyProperty" />
  </Property>

  <Condition Message="Property not found.">
    <![CDATA[MyProperty]]>
  </Condition>
</Product>
```

The problem I'm having is the `util:RegistrySearch` doesn't work in the setup project and the default `RegistrySearch` doesn't work in 64-bits if I don't set the package to 64-bit (which I can't use due other requirements).

Is there a way to have the `util:RegistrySearch` working to set the `Condition`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`util:RegistrySearch` is only useful in bundle authoring, not MSI package authoring. But "plain" RegistrySearch can search the 64-bit registry even from a 32-bit package; just specify `@Win64="yes"`.

Comment: But then I get the  warning 'ICE80: This 32Bit Package is using 64 bit Locator Type in RegLocator table entry MyRegistrySearch'.

Comment: Yes, it's a warning because you can't use things like paths that are in the 64-bit portions of the file system. But other values, or even just existence of particular registry values, are fine.

Comment: Where does "@Win64="yes"" go?