# Wix Bootstrapper RegistrySearch NOT finding value

Tags: wix, registry, 32bit-64bit, bootstrapper

I'm trying to search the registry in my Bootstrapper **Bundle** file to **check if a program is firstly installed** and a second search to check the **bitness** of the program installed.

Then I want to use the values returned to either **install** a **32bit or 64bit driver** for the program.

The issue is that in the log file created when I run this in cmd: **Bootstrapper.exe -l "c:\temp\LogFileName.log"**, I get this line:

```
[52BC:4F84][2023-05-17T12:59:37]i000: Registry value not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\[COMPANY_NAME]\', Value = 'Bitness'
```

I added Bitness as a string value into the registry editor and put the value as 64 as the program is indeed 64bit.

These are my registry searches:

```
<!-- Check if program is installed -->  
<util:RegistrySearch Id="CheckProgramInstalled"
                        Root="HKLM"
                        Key="SOFTWARE\[COMPANY_NAME]\[PRODUCTNAME]"
                        Result="exists"
                        Variable="ProgramInstalled" />
<!-- Check bitness of the program -->   
<util:RegistrySearch Id="CheckProgramBitness"
                        After="CheckProgramInstalled"
                        Root="HKLM"
                        Key="SOFTWARE\[COMPANY_NAME]\[PRODUCTNAME]"
                        Value="Bitness"
                        Result="value"
                        Variable="ProgramBitness" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there are at least two separate issues here.

**Unrecognised / empty properties**

Your registry search includes this key:

> Key="SOFTWARE\[COMPANY_NAME]\[PRODUCTNAME]"

but the error message reports the key like this:

> Key = 'SOFTWARE\[COMPANY_NAME]\'

This suggests:

1. the `[COMPANY_NAME]` property is not recognised (are you sure the underscore is correct?);
2. the `[PRODUCTNAME]` property is empty.

You could check whether these properties are being set correctly, or consider using WiX variables instead - [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772899/why-productcode-can-be-expaneded-while-productname-can-not) might help.

**Bitness-specific registry views**

By default, `<util:RegistrySearch>` searches the 32-bit registry view. This is critical in your case because if you have the 64-bit application installed then your registry search won't find the relevant keys. For more information on registry redirection, see [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys).

To search the 64-bit registry view, you will need to set `Win64="yes"`. See the accepted answers and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26873664/registrysearch-in-wix-is-not-returning-true-for-a-value-that-is-in-the-registry) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21315011/using-utilregistrysearch-to-search-64-bit-registry-in-wix-setup-project).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes I did have the product name wrong, due to some other files in my project using `[PRODUCTNAME]` as a variable I assumed this file could read that as well but when I put the name of the product in manually, it worked. The `[COMPANY_NAME]` was just a placeholder. And the **RegistrySearch** does indeed now work after I put in the **Win64="yes"** :)